# Loop with ChildWindows in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, childwindow

I have a control with textbox. After user input few lines of text and submit that by button then, for every line of text I need to show a childwindow with grid where user has to select some value.

Let's say that user inputs 5 lines of text with names of clients (one line one client name).

For every of them aften click Submit, he must select Salesperson from ChildWindow.

Of course now effect of my loop is opening 5 ChildWindows with the in the same time.

How can I do user get next ChildWindow only after choosing an element from Childwindow grid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your control could use a class that looks something like this.

```
public class SalesPersonSelector
{
    private Queue<string> _clientNamesToProcess;
    private Dictionary<string, SalesPerson> _selectedSalesPersons;
    private Action<IDictionary<string, SalesPerson>> _onComplete;
    private string _currentClientName;

    public void ProcessNames(IEnumerable<string> clientNames, Action<IDictionary<string, SalesPerson>> onComplete)
    {
        this._clientNamesToProcess = new Queue<string>(clientNames);
        this._selectedSalesPersons = new Dictionary<string, SalesPerson>();
        this._onComplete = onComplete;
        this.SelectSalespersonForNextClient();
    }

    private void SelectSalespersonForNextClient()
    {
        if (this._clientNamesToProcess.Any())
        {
            this._currentClientName = this._clientNamesToProcess.Dequeue();
            ChildWindow childWindow = this.CreateChildWindow(this._currentClientName);
            childWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(childWindow_Closed);
            childWindow.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            this._onComplete(this._selectedSalesPersons);
        }
    }

    private ChildWindow CreateChildWindow(string nextClientName)
    {
        // TODO: Create child window and give it access to the client name somehow.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void childWindow_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var salesPerson = this.GetSelectedSalesPersonFrom(sender as ChildWindow);
        this._selectedSalesPersons.Add(this._currentClientName, salesPerson);
        this.SelectSalespersonForNextClient();
    }

    private SalesPerson GetSelectedSalesPersonFrom(ChildWindow childWindow)
    {
        // TODO: Get the selected salesperson somehow.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Assuming your control has already split up the names from the TextBox into a list called "names", then you can do this:

```
var salesPersonSelector = new SalesPersonSelector();
salesPersonSelector.ProcessNames(names, selections =>
    {
        foreach (var selection in selections)
        {
            var clientName = selection.Key;
            var salesPerson = selection.Value;
            // TODO: Do something with this information.
        }
    });
```

I haven't tested this, but Visual Studio isn't giving me any red squiggly lines.